# Merge function in C with pointers

Tags: c, mergesort

I've been given an assignment to create function which merges 2 increasingly sorted lists, without creating additional one, only with pointers. It would be lovely if someone would give me a hint or a reasoning why my code is failing to do so:(

```
node_t *merge(node_t *l1, node_t *l2) {
    node_t *i;
    node_t dummy;
    i = &dummy;
    if (l1->value < l2->value) {
        dummy.next = l1;
        l1 = l1->next;
    } else {
        dummy.next = l2;
        l2 = l2->next;
    }
    while (i->next != NULL) {
        if (l1->value < l2->value && l1->next != NULL) {
            i->next = l1;
            l1 = l1->next;
        }
        if (l1->value >= l2->value && l2->next != NULL) {
            i->next = l2;
            l2 = l2->next;
        }
    }
    return dummy.next;
}
```

Comment: You know you are destroying the existing lists?

Comment: In your while loop, the second if is executed even when the first if was executed. Shouldn't that be an `else if`?

Comment: Your while loop terminates even when one of the lists is not exhausted yet.

Comment: Best way forward: take a debugger and step through the code.

Comment: well you can start with initializing dummy.. the next pointer is probably some arbitrary address

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a *dummy* node, you have all necessary nodes... Just change the links...

First determine which list contains the lower element:

```
node *finalList;
if (l1->value<l2->value) {
    finalList = l1;
    l1 = l1->next;
} else {
    finalList = l1;
    l1 = l1->next;
}
```

then use a pointer to move through the final list:

```
node *current = finalList;
```

Now loop over the lists:

```
while(true) {
    if (l1->value<l2->value) {
        current->next = l1;
        current = current->next; // one more in the final list from l1
        l1 = l1->next;           // move in l1
        if (l1==NULL) {          // l1 empty, everything remains in l2
            current = l2;
            break;
        }
    } else {
        current->next = l2;
        current = current->next;
        l2 = l2->next;
        if (l2==NULL) {
            current = l1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You just have to tackle empty lists at start...

Answer (score 0):

Your function has some problems:

- it will have undefined behavior if either argument list is empty,
- the test for the ends of lists are incorrect: once the sublist with the lower element is reduced to a single element, the loop runs forever without any effect.

Using a dummy node to simplify the code is not a problem, here is how to fix your function:

```c
node_t *merge(node_t *l1, node_t *l2) {
    node_t dummy;
    node_t *i = &dummy;
    for (;;) {
        if (l1 == NULL) {
            // list 1 exhausted: link in the rest of list 2
            i->next = l2;
            break;
        }
        if (l2 == NULL) {
            // list 2 exhausted: link in the rest of list 1
            i->next = l1;
            break;
        }
        if (l1->value <= l2->value) {
            // list 1 element comes before: link it in and skip to the next
            i = i->next = l1;
            l1 = l1->next;
        } else {
            // list 2 element comes before: link it in and skip to the next
            i = i->next = l2;
            l2 = l2->next;
        }
    }
    // return the combined list head
    return dummy.next;
}
```

A more typical C implementation would use a pointer to the list link:

```c
node_t *merge(node_t *l1, node_t *l2) {
    node_t *head;
    node_t **pp = &head;
    for (;;) {
        if (l1 == NULL) {
            // list 1 exhausted: link in the rest of list 2
            *pp = l2;
            break;
        }
        if (l2 == NULL) {
            // list 2 exhausted: link in the rest of list 1
            *pp = l1;
            break;
        }
        if (l1->value <= l2->value) {
            // list 1 element comes before: link it in and skip to the next
            *pp = l1;
            pp = &l1->next;
            l1 = l1->next;
        } else {
            // list 2 element comes before: link it in and skip to the next
            *pp = l2;
            pp = &l2->next;
            l2 = l2->next;
        }
    }
    // return the combined list head
    return head;
}
```

Here is a much simpler function to merge the lists without a dummy node or a double pointer. Note however that this recursive function does not use tail recursion: it will recurse many times using stack space proportional to the combined lengths of the argument lists, potentially causing a **stack overflow**.

```c
node_t *merge(node_t *l1, node_t *l2) {
    if (l1 == NULL)
        return l2;
    if (l2 == NULL)
        return l1;
    if (l1->value <= l2->value) {
        l1->next = merge(l1->next, l2);
        return l1;
    } else {
        l2->next = merge(l1, l2->next);
        return l2;
    }
}
```